# Select element with font family Verdana and font size misaligns the option selected

Tags: html, firefox, select, fonts

When a verdana font-family is used as font style for a select element, it works fine in Chrome and IE. But it behaves differently in Firefox, with the selected option overlapping the dropdown arrow. Can anyone please suggest a solution?

http://jsbin.com/onixuz/1/edit

Comment: No repro here. FF 21.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just moved your inline stlye to a style sheet:

```
select {font: 12px verdana;}
```

and it seems to work for me.